# How to type special characters in this forum?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, internationalization

The general rule used in LaTeX doesn't work: for example, typing `M\"{o}bius` and `Cram\'{e}r` doesn't give the desired outputs.

Comment: This might be how LaTeX is meant to handle it; it seems like the `\"` command doesn't naturally work in math mode ([see here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98052/umlauts-in-math-mode)). I'm not sure what the way to get an umlaut on this site is other than directly as a unicode character or using `\unicode{0x00E4}`  or something like that (in which case, it renders not italicized, which is troublesome)

Comment: Even I don't put them inside math mode, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh. Far as I know, MathJax only applies to math mode; everything else is handled by SE's markup. (e.g. \textbf{This text is bold} doesn't do anything). I suspect the best solution at the moment is just use unicode characters (though this involves copying and pasting and general annoyance).

Comment: All right, thank you for your reply. It makes sense.

Comment: If your problem is largely about typing the names of mathematicians respecting their national language conventions, then  copy/pasting from [this list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8709/11619) is also an option albeit a kludgy one. Users familiar with these things have compiled that list. I do realize that you are aware of how the names are supposed to be spelled, and only ask for help with the input.

Comment: Well, how do you type "special characters" on a computer? There's nothing special about math.SE.

Comment: For the body of the post one can just use the HTML entities. They are often relatively easy to remember. For example &uuml; gives u UMLaut so ü and &auml; gives ä etc.  (It does not work in comments or titles though). It is a bit clunky but for titles and comments one can copy from the preview of a post.

Comment: @Solitary alternatively use htnl - they are easy to find.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also wanted to type Möbius, etc, just as in LaTeX, by typing <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>... so I've made a [userscript](https://github.com/normalhuman/MathShortcuts2) for that. To use it,

1. Install a userscript manager (e.g., Tampermonkey extension for Chrome or Greasemonkey extension for Firefox)
2. [Click here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/normalhuman/MathShortcuts2/master/MathShortcuts2.user.js) to add the userscript.

Besides the common diacritics, the script enables shortcuts for "blackboard bold" letters and math operator names: see the [readme file](https://github.com/normalhuman/MathShortcuts2/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thank you very much, I can type Möbius now!

Comment: I updated the script: if you reinstall it (by clicking the same link) it will also replace \" followed by {o}. (The braces are unnecessary here, though.)

Comment: Möbius and Möbius, fantastic, thanks again~

Comment: Möbius seems to work for me. There doesn't seem to be a reason you should be in math mode if you are typing a word...

Comment: @BenSmith I'm not sure why you mention math mode here; my userscript has nothing to do with math mode. It simply substitutes a character with a diacritic for a combination of other characters, and happens to borrow those combinations from the LaTeX  _text mode_ syntax.

Comment: Are you saying that you are having issues with accented characters in code mode then? Because regular text seems to appear just fine.

Comment: @BenSmith I do not think there is any issue with the appearance of accented characters. Rather the question is how to input them (most conveniently). The script in this answer allows to input them using LaTeX-like syntax (which normally would not work).

Answer (score 10):

It would be a misconception to consider the source of a post as somehow analogous to the source of a LaTeX document (not only diacritics but quite literally *nothing* works *except* of course the math-environment). Instead it is better to think of the source of a HTML page. The basic formatting is done via Markdown and HTML.

Only there is extra support for typesetting mathematics via MathJax, whose syntax happens to be similar to the one of LaTeX.

As a consequence special characters can be inserted for example

1. by some direct method, for instance for many a user "é" or "ö" are just as easy to type as "n" (it is just some button on their keyboard), some combination of keystrokes (which one depends on the set-up), copy-paste.
2. using the methods provided by HTML such as using the name of HTML entities with the systax `&name;` where "name" is the name of the character, which is at least sometimes is not that hard to remember. For a list see for example [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

I mention 1. as in LaTeX  by default this is in fact not possible. For 2. it should be noted that this does not work in titles and comments, but creating the character in (the preview of)  the body and copy-pasting is an option.

Comment: òóôõöøőœìíîïīįıùúûüūůűųýþťțţŕřèéêëēėęěĕəàáâãäåæāăąźżžçćčñńņňß§śšşďđģğķĺļľł♧◇♡♤■□●○•°☆▪¤《》¡¿ on samsung keyboard in US english on an android mobile phone.

Answer (score 7):

There are certain system-dependent ways to enter diacriticals and other special characters.  For example, on a Macintosh computer running any operating system prior to 10.10 (Yosemite):

- The keystroke combination `option-U + vowel` produces the vowel with an umlaut over it.
- The keystroke combination `option-E + vowel` produces the vowel with an accent over it.

Further keystroke combinations for the Mac are listed [here](http://www.corpbuscards.com/mackeycodesfortyping.htm).

Beginning with Macintosh OS 10.10 (Yosemite) there is an [even simpler way to produce such characters](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18436?locale=en_US):  simply press and hold the desired vowel key on the keyboard, and a palette of accented versions of that vowel will appear on screen.

Slightly more elaborate methods exist in Windows; see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/type-and-display-accents-and-diacritical-marks) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/110605/how-do-i-type-accented-characters-in-windows).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the standard implementation of Mathjax, the `M\"{o}bius` will not render.

Workaround:

```
\ddot{o}
```

will give:

$$ \ddot{o} $$

Probably this is helpful for some.

Another workaround is to specify another font for the text in Mathjax:

```
"HTML-CSS": {
    styles: {
        ".MathJax .mtext": {
            "font-family": "sans-serif !important"
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you have access to the local HTML/CSS files:

```
.MathJax .mtext {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: $\ddot{o}$ is most definitely not an ö

Comment: I know, but at least the font stays the same. Here you can compare both versions rendered: https://www.matheretter.de/rechner/tex/?tex=%24%24%20%5Ctext%7B%20Kämpfer%20%7D%20vs.%20K%5Cddot%7Ba%7Dmpfer%20%24%24 - Unfortunately, it seems that the the \ddot{} is not working within a \text{} block. And yes, I wished it would work by default. -- PS: \"{o} is also no "ö" ;-)

Comment: Actually a LaTeX \"{o} is an ö with the correct font encoding (T1 for example), but the big problem with $\ddot{o}$ is that the dots are horribly misplaced. I would **hate** to see my own last name written Wikstr$\ddot{o}$m.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly less ugly than one answer offered is: \ddot{\mathsf a} $\ddot{\mathsf a}$ - but it's slightly bold and for all the extra typing it's better to find a webpage with the characters and copy/paste them (assuming you're using a cellphone or a keyboard without the characters).

Sources from webpages are:

- language specific ones such as: [open central unrounded vowel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel), [Germanic umlaut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut) - those offer explanations of history and usage, along with a litany of links.
- [Big list of Diaeresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)) (single, double, above, below, offset: dots and lines) at Wikipedia, and ones linked to [various diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla).
- Search websites such as [&what;](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/space) allow searches for all the Unicode characters.

You can copy them from here also: ä ö ü

Latin
Ä   ä
Ǟ   ǟ
Ą̈  ą̈
B̈  b̈
C̈  c̈
Ë   ë
Ḧ   ḧ
Ï   ï
Ḯ   ḯ
K̈  k̈
M̈  m̈
N̈  n̈
Ö   ö
Ȫ   ȫ
Ǫ̈  ǫ̈
Ṏ   ṏ
P̈  p̈
Q̈  q̈
Q̣̈     q̣̈
S̈  s̈
T̈  ẗ
Ü   ü
Ǖ   ǖ
Ǘ   ǘ
Ǚ   ǚ
Ǜ   ǜ
Ṳ   ṳ
Ṻ   ṻ
Ṳ̄  ṳ̄
ᴞ
V̈  v̈
Ẅ   ẅ
Ẍ   ẍ
Ÿ   ÿ
Z̈  z̈

Greek
Ϊ   ϊ
ῒ  ΐ  ῗ
Ϋ   ϋ
ῢ ΰ ῧ
ϔ

Cyrillic
Ӓ   ӓ
Ё   ё
Ӛ   ӛ
Ӝ   ӝ
Ӟ   ӟ
Ӥ   ӥ
Ї   ї
Ӧ   ӧ
Ӫ   ӫ
Ӱ   ӱ
Ӵ   ӵ
Ӹ   ӹ
Ӭ   ӭ

The only MathJax used in this answer is in the first sentence, the remaining characters can all be copy/pasted off of this webpage and onto another Stack Exchange edit or comment box, as-is.