# Could we have predefined macros for naturals, integers, reals, and the like?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Request in title. Could we have site-wide predefined $\LaTeX$ macros `\N`, `\Z`, `\Q` and `\R` for $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, and  $\mathbb{R}$, respectively? Any short variant would also do, like `\NN`, or `\bN`, or what have you.

I think that dozens of thousands  of keystrokes would be saved by this.

Is it that there are such macros and I didn't figure them out?

Comment: Aside from [$\LaTeX$ shortcuts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25283), another related discussion on this meta is here: [Can custom TeX/MathJax commands be defined by default for a site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28066) Similar feature request on [meta.se]: [Enable blackboard bold TeX macros \N, \Z, \Q, \R, \C for ℕ, ℤ, ℚ, ℝ, ℂ () in MathJax configuration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343509).

Comment: [`\Bbb` exists and works albeit outdated.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22142/471884)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. I saw the other posts and I think that $\mathbf{N}$ was the most important argument. But I'd be happy to [follow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25283/rm-latex-shortcuts#comment99404_25283) [Asaf's standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25283/rm-latex-shortcuts#comment99395_25283), and perhaps many people also would.